# Polynomial Class Project Problem with Division and Destructor C++

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, destructor, polynomials

This is a project for my object oriented programming class. I need to introduce the followings: overloading + to sum two polynomials, overloading * to multiply a polynomial with a scalar or to multiply it with another polynomial, overloading [] to return coeficient on a specific position, method for adding , deleting a coeficient and evaluating polynom in a certain point (f(x)).

1.Everything is working besides the destructor. The destructor that should be used (delete [] coef) of Polynomial will break (Heap Coruption) if i use cout << A + B and i do not know why.
What i use right now is a workaround but it will not delete coef[0]. That's the point where it breaks. If you can help me somehow i will be gratefull. Can you understand what caused it?

2.I need to have one more overloaded operator, " / ". It should make division between two polynomials and I do not know how to implement it. I tried to search for it but i couldn't understand any algorithm. Any advice or algorithm explanation would be great, because i really do not know from where to start and i need to finish it until tommorrow morning.

3.If you have any advice on coding or efficienty will also be great ( project requirement: do not use STL ).

Thank you!

Polynomial.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;

class Polynomial
{
    unsigned int deg;       
    double *coef;           

public:
    Polynomial() : deg(1), coef(new double[1]) {}                   

Polynomial(double [], int);                                     

Polynomial(Polynomial&);                                        

Polynomial& operator = (const Polynomial&);                     

~Polynomial();                                                  

friend ostream &operator <<(ostream&, const Polynomial&);       

friend istream &operator >>(istream&, Polynomial&);             

Polynomial operator + (const Polynomial) ;

double operator[] (unsigned int) const;

Polynomial operator * (int) const;

Polynomial operator * (const Polynomial obj) const;

unsigned int getDeg() { return this->deg; };                    

double eval(int);                                               

void addCoef(double, int);                                      

void delCoef(int);                                              

};

inline Polynomial::Polynomial(double coefficients[], int number) : deg(number), coef(new double[number])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < deg; i++) {
        coef[i] = coefficients[i];
    }
}

inline Polynomial::Polynomial(Polynomial &ob) {
    this->deg = ob.deg;
    this->coef = new double[deg];
    for (int i = 0; i <= deg; i++)
    {
        this->coef[i] = ob.coef[i];
    }
}

inline Polynomial::~Polynomial() {
    for (int i = this->deg; i > 0; i--)
        this->delCoef(i);
    this->coef[0] = 0;       //If i write it like this delete [] coef; it breaks.
    this->deg = 0;           //with HeapCoruption detected
}
```

Polynomial.cpp:

```
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator = (const Polynomial& obj)
{
if (this != &obj)       //Testing to avoid situations like A = A;
{
    this->deg = obj.deg;
    for (int i = 0; i <= obj.deg; i++)
        this->coef[i] = obj.coef[i];
}
return *this;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& in, Polynomial& obj) 
{ 
in >> obj.deg;
cout << endl;
obj.coef = new double[obj.deg];
for (int i = 0; i <= obj.deg; i++)
{
    in >> obj.coef[i];
}
return in;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Polynomial& obj) 
{
out << obj.deg << endl;
for (int i = 0; i <= obj.deg; i++)
{   
    if (obj.coef[i] != 0)
    {
        if (obj.coef[i] < 0)
            out << '(' << obj.coef[i] << ')';
        else
            out << obj.coef[i];
        if (i > 1)
            out << "*x^" << i;
        if (i == 1)
            out << "*x";
        if (i != obj.deg)
            out << " + ";
    }
}
out << endl <<endl;
return out;
}

Polynomial Polynomial::operator+ (const Polynomial obj)
{
Polynomial aux;

if (obj.deg >= deg)
{
    aux.deg = obj.deg;
    aux.coef = new double[obj.deg];

    for (int i = 0; i <= deg; i++)
        aux.coef[i] = obj.coef[i] + coef[i];

    for (int i = deg + 1; i <= obj.deg; i++)
        aux.coef[i] = obj.coef[i];
}
else // obj.deg < this->deg
{
    aux.deg = deg;
    aux.coef = new double[deg];

    for (int i = 0; i <= obj.deg; i++)
    {
        aux.coef[i] = obj.coef[i] + coef[i];
    }

    for (int i = obj.deg + 1; i <= deg; i++)
    {
        aux.coef[i] = coef[i];
    }
}

return aux;
}

double Polynomial::operator[] (unsigned int pos) const
{
if (pos > this->deg) {
    throw std::out_of_range("Index bigger than polynomial length");
}
return this->coef[pos];
}

Polynomial Polynomial::operator * (const int scalar) const
{
Polynomial aux;
aux.deg = this->deg;
aux.coef = new double[aux.deg];
for (int i = 0; i <= aux.deg; i++)
    aux.coef[i] = this->coef[i] * scalar;
return aux;
}

Polynomial Polynomial::operator * (const Polynomial obj) const
{
Polynomial aux;
aux.deg = obj.deg + this->deg;
aux.coef = new double[aux.getDeg()];
for (int i = 0; i <= aux.getDeg(); i++)
    aux.addCoef(0, i);

for (int i = 0; i <= this->deg; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j <= obj.deg; j++)
        aux.coef[i+j] += (this->coef[i]) * obj.coef[j];

return aux;
}

double Polynomial::eval(int x) {
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= this->deg; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
        sum += this->coef[0];
    else
    {
        int aux = i;
        int xaux = x;
        aux--;
        while (aux != 0)
        {
            xaux *= x;
            aux--;
        }
        sum += this->coef[i] * xaux;
    }
}
return sum;
}

void Polynomial::addCoef(double NewCoef, int pos)
{
if (pos < 0)
    return;

if (pos > this->deg)
{
    double *newCoef = new double[pos];
    for (int i = 0; i <= this->deg; i++)
        newCoef[i] = this->coef[i];
    for (int i = this->deg + 1; i < pos; i++)
        newCoef[i] = 0;
    newCoef[pos] = NewCoef;
    this->coef = newCoef;
    this->deg = pos;
    return;
}
else
{
    this->coef[pos] = NewCoef;
}
}

void Polynomial::delCoef(int pos) 
{
if (pos > this->deg || pos < 0 )
    return;
if (pos == this->deg)
{
    this->coef[pos] = 0;
    int degNoua = pos - 1;
    while (this->coef[pos] == 0 && pos != 0)
        pos--;
    if (pos == 0 && this->coef[pos] == 0)
    {
        delete this->coef;
        this->deg = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        this->deg = pos;
        double *aux = new double[pos];
        for (int i = 0; i <= pos; i++)
            aux[i] = this->coef[i];
        this->coef = aux;
    }
}
else
{
    this->coef[pos] = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question? See also [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Your assignment operator, what happens when the memory allocated for `this->coef` is not the same as for `obj.coef`? Just about the same with *all* your functions. And your default constructor only allocates memory for a *single* value for `coef`, which means if you have two or more you will go out of bounds. Not to mention that loop conditions like `i <= obj.deg` are suspect, as they mean you need `obj.deg + 1` elements allocated. And you *don't* do that (for example in the input operator).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not using the standard library is very common for school/college homework or assignments. And learning how e.g. a dynamic "array" like vector works is IMO a valuable lesson. But once learned, using `std::vector` instead is the right way to go forward, even for school assignments.